# Suspicious processes starting with "[?/-]" with after upgrading to trusty

Tags: 14.04, process

I have just upgraded to Trusty (this may not be relevant).

I fired up top, and noticed a heap of processes running as root that I had not noticed before. For example:

```
234 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.86 [?/-1610198336]
235 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 [?/-1610198336]
236 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 [?/-1610198336]     `
```

So I ran the following ps command:

```
ps axu | grep ?\/ | grep root
```

which gave the following (redacted) output:

```
root       234  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:01 [?/-1610198336]
root       235  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       236  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       239  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       240  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       241  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       242  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       243  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       244  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       245  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       246  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       247  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       248  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       249  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       250  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       251  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-2144731094]
root       252  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       253  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       254  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       255  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       256  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       257  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       258  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       259  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       260  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       261  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       262  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       263  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       264  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       265  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       266  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/-1610198336]
root       267  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   14:38   0:00 [?/0]
```

A `lsof` doesn't explain much more to me:

`sudo lsof -p 423`

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
^X/-16101 423 root  cwd       DIR   8,66     4096    2 /
^X/-16101 423 root  rtd       DIR   8,66     4096    2 /
^X/-16101 423 root  txt   unknown                      /proc/423/exe
```

Can anyone explain the purpose of these processes?

- This is Ubuntu server without x installed.
- I am using ZFS, but not as a root file system using the zfs ppa.
- Other than the above, this is a very vanilla install.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1314358) bug report